# Permanently delete a page in Silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Using Silverstripe 4

I've got a page (URL Segment : careers-2) which when I try to rename to "careers" it never lets me.
I can't find a page with the URLSegment "careers" in the page list.
I also deleted entries where the URLSegment was "careers" from SiteTree,SiteTree_Live and SiteTree_Versions.

But it still doesn't let me take the "careers" url. Always reverts to careers-2. I can rename this to anything else "careers-3" etc but not "careers".
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue.
There was a route defined in routes.yml.
Therefore, SS naturally updated the page in question to a different one.

Leaving this here, in case someone stumbles upon a similar issue.